# locale loop doesn't get correct path

Tags: templating, localization, language

I'm trying to loop on locales to get the path to the current entry, but for the other locales (for a language switcher).

Here is my code:

```
{% set locales = craft.i18n.getSiteLocales() %}
{% for locale in locales %}

    {% set localeEntry = craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale(locale.id).first %}

        {{dump(localeEntry.locale)}}
        {{dump(localeEntry.getUrl()) }}

{% endfor %}
```

Results:

```
"en"
"http://website.dev/en/page"

"en_gb"
"http://website.dev/en/page"

"en_us"
"http://website.dev/en/page"

"de"
"http://website.dev/de/page"
```

The language only versions are fine `en` and `de`, though the language-location versions are incorrect. These are all set correctly in my config.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In your channel section, how did you define your url-format for your different locales?

Comment: Different for quite a few sections, sometimes just `{slug}`, sometimes `news/{slug}`. I never put `{locale}` in if that's what you're curious about? I've seen that isn't recommended.

Comment: Nevermind, sorted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue was my config set incorrectly. I was doing this:

```
'siteUrl' => array(
    'en' => 'http://website.dev/en',
    'en-gb' => 'http://website.dev/en-gb',
    'en-us' => 'http://website.dev/en-us',
    'en-au' => 'http://website.dev/en-au',
    'en-nz' => 'http://website.dev/en-nz'
),
```

When the array keys need to match the way they are set in craft with underscores (and your public/locale/index.php file)

```
'siteUrl' => array(
    'en' => 'http://website.dev/en',
    'en_gb' => 'http://website.dev/en-gb',
    'en_us' => 'http://website.dev/en-us',
    'en_au' => 'http://website.dev/en-au',
    'en_nz' => 'http://website.dev/en-nz'
),
```